# How to retrieve the value of a dropdown with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown which can select multiple values.I know that if the dropdown stores values comma separated its possible to split the string and retrieve the values. However I have a dropdown which on selection of multiple values stores them as a list with each value as a list element. I tried to retreive the values in the same way but I am only getting the first value! Can anyone suggest a way to retrieve all the values using JS?

The selected values from the dropdown basically fill a list dynamically. I need to know how to retrieve the values of the list.

The code of the list is:

The Javascript and HTML code is:

```
 var ul = document.getElementById("foo");
 var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
 {
     var it = items[i].getElementsByTagName("span");
     alert(it.innerHTML);

 } <ul id="foo">
 <li><span> Afghanistan</span>
 </li>
 <li><span> Afghanistan2</span>
 </li>
 <li><span> Afghanistan3</span>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Show us some code. and Its stores value in an array like `[1, 2, 3]` not comma separated string

Comment: show us some code sample that have you tried.

Comment: can you show to us your html code?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: your question talks about dropdown and the code example shows list..!!

Comment: I edited the question later. Apologies for the confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it compulsory to use raw JS?
In jQuery you can do this way:

```
$( "ul > li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

P.S. I'm using in this example ul > li selector, but i'm not sure that it's best solution in your case, because I can't see full markup of your page. According to the subject of your question I suppose you need to use some extra jQuery selector value to detect selected options. Something like that:

```
 if ($(this).is(':selected') {
//then process this value
}
```